# Host down alert in Prometheus when all scrape jobs are down

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a problem understanding and/or implementing the alert logic in Prometheus. I have two alert rules:

```
alert: JobDown
expr: up == 0
for: 5m
labels:
  severity: warning
annotations:
  summary: Scrape job {{ $labels.job }} down on {{ $labels.hostname }}.

alert: HostDown
expr: sum(up) == 0
for: 5m
labels:
  severity: critical
annotations:
  description: All scrape jobs down on {{ $labels.hostname }}.
  summary: Host {{ $labels.hostname }} down.
```

I would expect the HostDown alert to be triggered when all jobs are down, but it has not been the case: I have seen hosts being down, Prometheus was showing alerts for every scrape job, but did not fire the HostDown alert. Did I write the expression right?

Comment: What value does the `up` metric have for you when all jobs are down? Look in the Prometheus expression browser. Are you using Prometheus to scrape itself?

Comment: No, I do not have any Prometheus-own metrics, because I disabled that job. Up metric is 0 for every job down, when all jobs are down on a node the sum is also down. In the console I can use a host label, ie. `sum(up{hostname="somehost"})` and this is not possible in the rules config, but it seems like the expressions are evaluated with per target grouping by default, so expected the sum aggregation to have the per target scope too.

Comment: `sum` will ignore `hostname` and sum over everything. To sum over `hostname`, you'd need `sum by (hostname) (up) == 0`. Though I don't know where you're getting the `hostname` label from - it's not a standard label on `up`.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. Hostname is a custom label in my conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` will ignore `hostname` and sum over everything. To sum over `hostname`, you need

```
sum by (hostname) (up) == 0
```

*NB: hostname is not a standard `label` on `up`, it's a custom label in the configuration of the original poster*